# How to Split char or string using \ symbol?

Tags: c++, c, window

How to split a char in C Programming.

here code below.

char aa=Sanju\bala.

i want to split the aa into two values like Sanju and bala.
How can i resolve this?

thanks
Sanju

Answer (score 2):

Use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}

Output: 

Splitting string "- This, a sample string." into tokens:  
This 
a  
sample  
string
```

Comment: its not working in backslashes and front slashes...

Comment: Try to escape them http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Sanju\bala";
string[] splittedString = str.Split('\');
```

Hope this'll help. :):)

Comment: its not vc++...How can i add string headerfile?

Comment: Can u please post a bit of code, where u wanna implement it.